# MSaccess DAO.Recordset quit working when new column added to table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

When I tested this on a test file it worked great, but when I went to update the main file it did not work.

I am trying to pull the latest record in the SessionID column. I had to add this column in after the file had been used for a few days. I have a textbox on a form that when the app is loaded, it pulls the latest SessionID. You can submit items with this SessionID attached to the line, then when you press New Product button, the SessionID txtbox increments by 1. I added this code into my On Load, but for some reason will not load the latest sessions. It will pull client, or product code, or lot code, just not anything from the newly added Sessions_FRL column.

```
Dim rstSession As DAO.Recordset
Dim Session As Integer

Set rstSession = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Field_Return_Table where [Completed_By_FRL]='" & _
    UCase(Environ("USERNAME")) & "' and [ID]=" & DMax("ID", "Field_Return_Table", "[Completed_By_FRL]='" & UCase(Environ("USERNAME")) & "'"))

Me!txt_Session = rstSession!Session_FRL + 1

rstSession.Close
Set rstSession = Nothing
```

Any help as to why I can't pull data from the newly updated Table column?

Comment: Check resulting string of SQL you use for opening recordset first: type `?"select * from Field_Return_Table where..."` in Immediate window and try to "run" this query in query bilder. It may help to detect the problem. Actual code looks ok.

Comment: Are you working with a local Access table or a linked table?